# Pyramide of Stars Javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

How could I create Pyramide of Stars that increase every row **by 2** like that:

```
*
* * *
* * * * *
* * * * * * *
```

My currently code:

```
for (var x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
    for (var y = 0; y <= x; y = y + 1) {
        document.write(" * ");
    }
    document.write("<br>");
}
```

Comment: If you count `row` from 0, then you want `numberOfStars = row*2 + 1;` Now adjust the inner loop...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible just to increment in your loop by 2.

```
for(var i = 1; i < 20; i += 2) {
    console.log( Array(i).fill('*').join(' ') );
}
```

Otherwise just multiply inside your loop

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    console.log( Array(i*2 + 1).fill('*').join(' ') );
}
```

You may also need to [polyfill Array.fill](https://qa.polyfill.io/v2/docs/) depending on your target.

Comment: If you're going to use `fill`, you might as well use `repeat`.

Comment: that's also possible. but then you would need to trim it too and then you have the ugly looking space after the star: `'* '.repeat(i).trim()`. one could easily omit the space and ruin the effect?

Answer (score 2):

Other answers recreate the entire row each time. This solution just extends the row each time to have another star.

```js
function pyramid(n) {
  let result = '', str = '', add = '*';
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    str += add;
    add = ' *';
    if (!(i % 2)) result += str + '\n';
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(pyramid(5));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

```js
function generate() {
    var totalNumberofRows = 5;
    var output="";
    for (var i = 1; i <= totalNumberofRows; i++) {
      for (var j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        if(j==1)
          output+="*";
        else
          output+="     "+ "*" + "     "+ "*";
  }
  console.log(output);
      output="";
   }
}  
generate()
```

Comment: This solution is not very scalable, by which I mean, what if I want to print out every third, or tenth row?

Answer (score 0):

Hope so this is also beneficial for you....

$(document).ready(function () {

```
    var NumberofRows = 5,arr;
    for (var i = 1; i <= NumberofRows; i++) {
        pyramid = [];
        for (var j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
             pyramid.push('*');               
        }
        console.log(pyramid.join(" ") + "\n");
      }    
});
```

``

Answer (score -1):

```
var maxStar = 9

for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    let half = maxStar-i
    var totalSpaces = ' '.repeat(half)
    process.stdout.write(totalSpaces)
    for (let j = 0; j < i; j++) {
       process.stdout.write('* ')
    }
    process.stdout.write('\n')
}
```

Comment: Code output does not match what the question asks for: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY5NDoIwEIX3nGJ2LRKILI16CrZuJlBim0qbdkQTw9nrAEbd0M2X5v3MMzhibIP2VA6uUymNGOCGz4aYZzhkWe8CSKsINP/rI@ME9Z5ZFDm8MuA3q1e0PRs@0VIvwlxGjtA2HlsVWRcgqqC8QpJzIl9sPjhWYxWpc3eqHkGTkn@51fUdYriHBxgeohm/HVtVYgdi7Zi274nLwKYppTc "JavaScript (Node.js) – Try It Online") Also, there's no reason to use `var` anymore.